# Renombrar un fichero txt en C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy programando en visual c++ 2008 para smart device. Estoy intentando cambiar el nombre de un fichero txt. Tengo un codigo sacado de msdn de Microsoft pero no me funciona. El codigo compila bien y no da ningun error, pero no cambia el nombre del archivo. Alguna idea? Gracias.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int _tmain(void)
{
char oldname[] = "alarm.txt";
char newname[] = "prueba.txt";
int _wrename( wchar_t *oldname, wchar_t *newname);
return 0;
}
```

Este es el link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f(v=vs.90).aspx

Tambien he probado de este modo pero tampoco funciona.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "Windows.h"

int _tmain(void)
{
char oldname[] = "alarm.txt";
char newname[] = "prueba.txt";
_wrename(oldname, newname);
return 0;
}
```

me da este error: `Error    1   error C3861: 'wrename': no se encontró el identificador c:\Users\P\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rename a file C++ AML\Rename a file C++ AML\Rename a file C++ AML.cpp  13  Rename a file C++ AML`

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda que describieras con más detalle "*no me funciona*". ¿Te da un error? ¿No te compila?, por favor: edita la pregunta y añade más detalles.

Comment: Lo siento, ya esta editado.

Comment: Básicamente no estás llamando a `_wrename` si no declarando la función dentro de `t_main`, lo cuál no tiene sentido; cambia la llamada a `_wrename(oldname, newname);`

Comment: Ya lo habia probado pero me dice que no se ha encontrado el identificador `_wrename`

Comment: Edita la pregunta con el código que te falla y el error que recibes. Si incluyes [las cabeceras requeridas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx) (que parece que si) no debería estar fallando al compilar.

Comment: Por favor: edita el código. Seguramente (deduzco) no estás comprobando el retorno de la función `_wrename` que en caso de fallar devuelve un valor diferente a `0` y establece la variable `errno` a un valor que te sirve para diagnosticar el error. Pero sin ver el código que te falla, no lo puedo saber seguro.

Comment: Perdon por la espera, ya esta editado.

Answer (score 3):

`wchar_t` **no** es equivalente a `char`. En `wchar_t` un caracter puede ocupar más de 1 byte.

con `char` tienes que usar `rename`:

```
int _tmain()
{
  const char oldname[] = "alarm.txt";
  const char newname[] = "prueba.txt";
  rename(oldname, newname);
  return 0;
}
```

Para llamar a `_wrename` tienes que usar `wchar_t`:

```
int _tmain()
{
  const wchar_t oldname[] = L"alarm.txt";
  const wchar_t newname[] = L"prueba.txt";
  _wrename(oldname, newname);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @eferion. He probado los dos codigos que me has pasado pero me dice que no se han encontrado los identificadores  `rename`y `_wrename`. Creo que se debe a que uso una version de c++ antigua.

Comment: @Andermutu `_wrename` es la misma función que tienes en la pregunta... ¿no te faltarán includes?

Comment: si pero la diferencia es que en mi pregunta utilizo `int _wrename` y entonces no me salta ningun error. Por lo contrario cuando utilizo a secas `_wrename `si que me dice que no se ha encontrado el identificador.

Comment: @Andermutu con esto `int _wrename(...)` estás declarando una función... no llamándola. Ojo con eso

Comment: y entonces como podria solucionarlo, porque si no utilizo `int` me da un error.

Comment: @Andermutu `rename` se debería encontrar en `cstdio` y `_wrename` en `cstdio` o en `cwchar`

Comment: Y puede que no esten debido a que mi version de c++ es antigua, porque entonces deberia de ir buscando otra solucion...

Comment: @Andermutu esto está disponible desde, al menos, VS2005 según la [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zw5t957f(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: teniendo en cuenta que estoy desarrolando para smart device en aplicacion win 32?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62903/discussion-between-eferion-and-andermutu).

Answer (score 3):

Tiene que haber un motivo por el que no se te renombra el archivo, la función que estás usando puede reportar los siguientes errores:

- `EACCES` el archivo o directorio especificado por `newname` ya existe o no puede ser creado (ruta no válida); u `oldname` es un directorio y `newname` especifica una ruta diferente.
- `ENOENT` el archivo o ruta especificada por `oldname` no na sido encontrada.
- `EINVAL` el nombre contiene caracteres no válidos.

Para comprobar si la función de renombrado devuelve un error, debes comprobar si el retorno no es `0`:

```
const char oldname[] = "alarm.txt";
const char newname[] = "prueba.txt";

if (rename(oldname, newname))
{
    std::cout << "La operacion ha fallado con codigo " << errno << '\n';
}
```

En el código anterior, si la función devuelve algo que no sea `0`, se considerará que el `if` es verdadero y te mostrará el código de error, [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) puedes ver una lista de los códigos de error.

---

> Me da este error: `Error    1   error C3861: 'wrename': no se encontró el identificador c:\Users\P\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rename a file C++ AML\Rename a file C++ AML\Rename a file C++ AML.cpp  13  Rename a file C++ AML`

EL error se queja de `wrename` y tú estás usando en el código `_wrename` ¿**seguro que** estás pegando el mismo código que te da el error?

Comment: Perdona por la espera de nuevo. He probado tu codigo y me da el mismo error de no se encontro el identificador `rename`. Creo que puede a que en smart device no este disponible. Lo miro y lo comento.

Comment: Si era lo que pensaba, para smart device no puedo incluir rename, pero para una aplicacion de pc si.